# Sporadic Python error in while loop TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, grovepi+

Here's the portion of my script having errors:

```
while:
    sensorIn = 8
    sensorOut = 5
    sensorAC = 7
    blue = 0
    white = 1
    [tempIn, humIn] = grovepi.dht(sensorIn, 1)
    print("tempIn = %.02f C humIn =%.02f%%"%(tempIn, humIn))
    [tempOut, humOut] = grovepi.dht(sensorOut, 1)
    print("tempOut = %.02f C humOut =%.02f%%"%(tempOut, humOut))
    [tempAC, humAC] = grovepi.dht(sensorAC, 1)
    print("tempAC = %.02f C humAC =%.02f%%"%(tempAC, humAC))
```

It randomly errors out with:

```
TypeError: 'int' object not iterable on the line: [tempAC, humAC] = grovepi.dht(sensorAC, 1)
```

This is used with a Raspberry Pi and GrovePi board to take in readings from a temperature and humidity sensor. It will loop through, taking readings and then doing some things with those readings then sleep for 15 minutes before starting again.

Maybe the while loop is the issue...I used to run this without the while loop and would set it up in crontab to run every 15 minutes that way. Occasionally a reading would come in in error but would pass through the script as 0, the script would not stop and error out, it would continue through and just report the value as zero.

I've looked at a lot of different posts about this error but I've only come across ones where the error always comes up and doesn't allow the script to run through completion at all, in my case, it only happens occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue with the grovepi.dht function, caused occasionally possibly by issues with communication with the device. http://forum.dexterindustries.com/t/incorrect-readings-and-typeerror/1582/2

The solution is just to add exception handling for the type error, since it will just be an intermittent issue (see the linked post for an example of how to do this).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'll try adding the exception handling.